# [Web Scraping]Operation timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT) error when opening html with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, web-scraping, nokogiri

https://www.coupang.com/np/categories/310633?listSize=120&brand=&offerCondition=&filterType=&isPriceRange=false&minPrice=&maxPrice=&page=1&channel=user&fromComponent=N&selectedPlpKeepFilter=&sorter=saleCountDesc&filter=&component=310534&rating=0

I am trying to scrape/crawl this site using Nokogiri.
But I keep getting Operation timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT) error.
The same url works fine on Python so I do not think it's my internet connection or the website problem. Other sites work well using Nokogiri except the one above.

I kept on trying and sometimes it works and sometimes it throws timedout error after certain period of time.

```rb
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.coupang.com/np/categories/310633?listSize=120&brand=&offerCondition=&filterType=&isPriceRange=false&minPrice=&maxPrice=&page=1&channel=user&fromComponent=N&selectedPlpKeepFilter=&sorter=saleCountDesc&filter=&component=310534&rating=0"))
puts doc
```

This is the code I typed on rails console.
Running ruby file does not work either. Can anyone reproduce this error?

Comment: I think this is an http request problem. not nokogiri I cannot get response from the url given. I don't know why this is the case for ruby only. I am using 2.5.3

Comment: Step 1 for debugging is to use `nokogiri 'your url'` at the command line and see what happens. I get `"Operation timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)"` so it's either an invalid URL or it's being blocked somewhere.